# Using Javascript parseInt returns a different value

Tags: javascript, parseint

I'm not entirely sure why the string "6145390195186705543" is outputting 6145390195186705000, at first reading through the threads it may be the base radix but even tinkering around with that still gives me the same results, can anyone help explain because I do believe this is not a bug, but I'm not entirely sure what's the explanation here.

```
  const digits = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
  const val1 = digits.join('') // string "6145390195186705543"
  const test1 = Number(val1)  // outputs 6145390195186705000
  const test2 = parseInt(val1) // outputs 6145390195186705000
```

Comment: `6145390195186705543 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with `parseInt`. If you were to create the same number from a number literal, you'd get the same problem.

This happens because JavaScript stores numbers as double prescision floats, which offer approximately 16 significant decimal digits.

The only way to fix this is to not use the Number type. JavaScript has another number type, BigInt, which offers arbitrary precision integers. Here's how you can do it with it:

```
const digits = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
const val1 = digits.join('') 
const test3 = BigInt(val1) // 6145390195186705543n - The n at the end means it's a BigInt
```